# SQL Query Help on finding Extended ASCII

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can I make a select statement to seaqrch for HI-ASCII characters for ex..chinese charatcres

Thanx

Comment: Note that there are no HI-ASCII characters, ASCII only defines character 1-128; anything beyond that is encoding-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

just add N before any value you want to search for for example

select * from [Table] where [Name]like N'% 的 %'

N= for search extended ascii characters